# Merge / Join Undefined Number of Lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, join, merge, counter

I have an undefined number of lists, obtained from splitting an undefined number of extracted tweets together.

In an already existing main function (I can not modify this or the grader will not function), I need to merge these lists of words into a single list of words so that I can use the Counter tool.

So...this is a SUBSET of my output...

```
['httptcozknmgr']
['ashtonsos', 'ahs']
['its', 'too', 'late', 'to', 'apologize']
```

I want a single list to contain all of these, and the rest that are not shown, into a list that looks like:

```
['httptcozknmgr', 'ashtonsos', 'ahs', 'its', 'too', 'late', 'to', 'apologize', .........AND ON AND ON AND ON]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use .extend.

```
lst=["word1"]
lst1=["word2","word3"]
lst.extend(lst1)
```

this will create one list that looks like so:

```
["word1","word2","word3"]
```

pairing this with some kind of loop should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['httptcozknmgr'],
['ashtonsos', 'ahs'],
['its', 'too', 'late', 'to', 'apologize']]

import itertools
print itertools.chain(*my_list)
```

or see any of the links in the related section to your right

Comment: Isn't this assuming I have only THREE lists?  There may be 100,000 lists...I need them ALL combined into a single list.

Comment: You'd need a `list` call in there to materialize it.